# Send customized bulk SMS with twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I want to send different messages to multiple users at once. I read the article here: https://www.twilio.com/blog/send-bulk-sms-twilio-node-js-html but it mentions nothing about sending customized messages. The only difference in my messages is the user's name.

The best solution I can think of is to create x number of API calls to send messages to x numbers. I believe that's going to be time taking. Is it possible to do it with one API call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist, and author of that post, here.

You are right, there is not currently a Twilio service that allows you to send bulk messages with customised messages with one single API call. You will have to make an [API call to the messages resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-resource#create-a-message-resource) for each message you want to send.

When sending messages in bulk, I recommend you read and understand this article on [Twilio rate limits and message queues](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002943027-Understanding-Twilio-Rate-Limits-and-Message-Queues). That will ensure you are successful in sending your messages.